# Prove that there exists at least one point $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t_0) = 0$ for all $f \in \mathscr F.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Let $\mathscr F$ be an infinite family of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ with the property that given any finite subfamily of functions $\mathscr F' \subset \mathscr F,$ there exists at least one point $t \in [0,1]$ (depending on the subfamily) such that $f(t) = 0$ for all $f \in \mathscr F'.$ Prove that there exists at least one point $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t_0) = 0$ for all $f \in \mathscr F.$

How do I proceed to prove it? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subseteq \mathscr F.$ Now I am considering a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f_k (t_n) = 0,$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and for all $n \in \Bbb N.$ Then it will have a convergent subsequence $\{t_{n_k} \}_{k \geq 1}.$ Let $t_0 \in [0,1]$ be it's limit. Then $f_n (t_0) = 0,$ for all $n \in \Bbb N.$ Is it of any importance?

Comment: It is better to post your comment inside the question box. Otherwise someone may think that you have made no effort and vote your question for closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_f=\{t: f(t)=0\}$ for $f \in \mathcal F$. Then $A_f$ is closed, hence compact, by continuity of $f$. This family of compact set has finite intersection property: the intersection of any finite number of them is non-empty by hypothesis. Now compactness of $[0,1]$ implies that intersection of all of these sets is non-empty which is what we have to prove.

Comment: Can you give more details about the last line?

Comment: @A learner see here **Theorem 5.3** https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:d22769f0-38a9-4798-8bc7-ca936efb8e93

Comment: You only need to remark the $A_f = f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ are closed, and have the FIP and the compactness of $[0,1]$ does the rest.